# How to wrap up Ant Design with Styled Components and TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, antd, styled-components

I want to wrap up my ant-design components with styled-components, I know that this is possible (https://gist.github.com/samuelcastro/0ff7db4fd54ce2b80cd1c34a85b40c08) however I'm having troubles to do the same with TypeScript.

This is what I have so far:

```js
import { Button as AntButton } from 'antd';
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button/button';
import styledComponents from 'styled-components';

interface IButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
   customProp: string;
}

export const Button = styledComponents<IButtonProps>(AntButton)`
  // any custom style here
`;
```

As you can see I'm defining my ant-design button with `as any` in order to make it work, otherwise I get some incompatible types like:

```
Argument of type 'typeof Button' is not assignable to parameter of
type 'ComponentType<IButtonProps>'.

Type 'typeof Button' is not assignable to type
'StatelessComponent<IButtonProps>'.

Types of property 'propTypes' are incompatible.

 Property 'customProp' is missing in type '{ 
    type: Requireable<string>; 
    shape: Requireable<string>; 
    size: Requireable<string>; 
    htmlType: Requireable<string>; 
    onClick: ...
    etc
 }
```

Thank you.

**Solution:**

```
import { Button as AntButton } from 'antd';
import { NativeButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button/button';
import * as React from 'react';
import styledComponents from 'styled-components';

export const Button = styledComponents<NativeButtonProps>(props => <AntButton {...props} />)`
    // custom-props
`;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could be a bit more specific - what exactly are the issues you're facing? The more info you can give (preferably showing your code, too), the more people will be able to help :)

Comment: @JoeClay Thanks added more info.

Comment: Please add your imports to the question.  I'm guessing `import styledComponents from "styled-components"` and `import { Button as AntButton } from "antd"` but I can't guess where `IButtonProps` comes from.

Comment: @MattMcCutchen Added imports. Thanks!

Comment: Just tried: `export const Button = styledComponents<IButtonProps, any>(AntButton)` and it seems to be working fine, I just don't know what does the second type parameter of `styledComponents<IButtonProps, any>` mean.

Comment: The solution you posted works also with `react-emotion`. Thank you!!

Answer (score 17):

I have found this ancient question and try to solve in an easy way:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import { CardProps } from 'antd/lib/card';

export const NewCard: React.FunctionComponent<CardProps> = styled(Card)`
  margin-bottom: 24px;
`;
```

without render props :D

if you just need wrap a component as function component, that's all right. But you will lose the properties of class component such as `Card.Meta`.

There is a workaround:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Card } from 'antd';
import { CardProps } from 'antd/lib/card';

export const NewCard: typeof Card = styled(Card)<CardProps>`
  margin-bottom: 24px;
` as any;
```

Everything (maybe... XD) works as original Antd Component ;)

Answer (score 8):

The above solutions didn't work for me, this solved it though.

```
const Button = styled((props: NativeButtonProps) => <AntButton {...props} />)``;
```

Answer (score 5):

my code is here. and it is work.

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button as AntButton } from 'antd';
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button/button';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Container = styled.div`
  font-size: 20px;
`;


const Button: React.FunctionComponent<ButtonProps> = styled(AntButton)`
  margin-top: 24px;
  margin-left: 30px;
`;

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <Container>
      Hello World
      <Button type="primary">test</Button>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The root of the problem seems to be that `styled-components` expects the inner component (`AntButton`) to accept *all* the props in the specified interface (`IButtonProps`), but `AntButton` does not accept `customProp`.  To fix this, follow the last example in [this section](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#styling-components) of the documentation and use a stateless function component to remove `customProp` before calling `AntButton`.

```
export const Button = styledComponents<IButtonProps>(
  ({ customProp, ...rest }) => <AntButton {...rest} />)`
  // any custom style here
`;
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, this worked just fine, however now when I try to use my new Button component with like: `<Button onClick={prop.onChange}/>` Typescript complains about: `Type '{ onClick: any; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<ThemedOuterStyledProps<WithOptionalTheme<ButtonProps, ThemeInterface>, ThemeInterface>>'. Property 'style' is missing in type '{ onClick: any; }'.`.

Comment: Ok I fixed this problem importing `NativeButtonProps` instead of `ButtonProp` from antd.

Answer (score 1):

index.tsx (Button Component)

```js
import { Button as AntButton } from 'antd'
import { NativeButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button/button'
import 'antd/lib/button/style/css'
import * as React from 'react'
import styledComponents from 'styled-components'
import * as colours from '../colours'

const getColour = (props: any) =>
  props.status === 'green'
    ? colours.STATUS_GREEN
    : props.status === 'red'
      ? colours.STATUS_RED
      : props.type === 'primary'
        ? colours.PRIMARY
        : colours.WHITE

export interface ButtonProps extends NativeButtonProps {
  status?: string
}

export default styledComponents((props: ButtonProps) => <AntButton {...props} />)`
  &:focus,
  &:hover
  & {
    background-color: ${getColour};
    border-color: ${getColour};
  }
`
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.5.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.5.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```js
import React from 'react'
import Button, { ButtonProps } from './index'

interface ButtonAsyncSingleSuccessProps extends ButtonProps {
  clickFunc: any, // (...args: any[]) => Promise<any>
  labelLoading: string,
  labelReady: string,
  labelSuccess: string,
}

interface ButtonAsyncSingleSuccessState {
  label: string,
  loading: boolean,
  status: string
}

export default class ButtonAsyncSingleSuccess extends React.Component<
  ButtonAsyncSingleSuccessProps,
  ButtonAsyncSingleSuccessState
> {
  constructor (props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      label: props.labelReady,
      loading: false,
      status: ''
    }
  }
  public clickHandler (event: any) {
    const { labelLoading, labelReady, labelSuccess, clickFunc } = this.props
    this.setState({
      label: labelLoading,
      loading: true,
      status: ''
    })
    clickFunc(event)
      .then(() => {
        this.setState({
          label: labelSuccess,
          loading: false,
          status: 'green'
        })
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.setState({
          label: labelReady,
          loading: false,
          status: 'red'
        })
      })
  }
  public render () {
    const {
      labelLoading,
      labelReady,
      labelSuccess,
      clickFunc,
      ...props
    } = this.props
    const { label, loading, status } = this.state
    if (status === 'red') {
      setTimeout(() => this.setState({ status: '' }), 1000) // flash red
    }
    return (
      <Button
        {...props}
        loading={loading}
        status={status}
        onClick={(e) => this.clickHandler(e)}
      >
        {label}
      </Button>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to make AntdButton reusable and pass different styles in each case?

Comment: I think you could easily do that by passing different style name props.