# How override a Button Ant Design with styled component and typescripts?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components, antd

I want to override a Button Ant Design with typescript and styled component to personalize the style. But when I try te result is not good.

I try some test but never I have the good display.

I try like this [How to wrap up Ant Design with Styled Components and TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704785/how-to-wrap-up-ant-design-with-styled-components-and-typescript) but no result.

But the result haven't the style of ant Design component but the button inherite the Button ant design and her props.

ButtonStyledComponent

```
import { Button as AntButton } from "antd";
import { NativeButtonProps } from "antd/lib/button/button";
import * as React from "react";
import styledComponents from "styled-components";

export const Button = styledComponents<NativeButtonProps>(props => (
  <AntButton {...props} />
))`
   pType: string;
   pSize: string;
   pShape: string;
`;
```

Button

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Button } from "./ButtonStyleComponent";

export interface ButtonProps {
  pType?: "primary" | "secondary" | "danger";
  pSize?: "small" | "medium" | "large";
  pShape?: "round" | "rect";
}

class Button extends React.Component<ButtonProps> {
  render() {
    return (
      <Button
        {...this.props}
        pType={this.props.pType}
        pSize={this.props.pSize}
        pShape={this.props.pShape}
      >
        {this.props.children}
      </Button>
    );
  }
}
```

export { Button };

the problem is when I execute this code, I see just an ugly grey Button and not a Button with the design of the Ant Design Button.

The other problem is when I try to call the method of a Ant Design Button, the method is not recognize (ex: the method onClick ).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of something I've done that's fairly similar using `antd`

```
import { Button } from 'antd'
import { ButtonProps } from 'antd/lib/button'
import useStyles from 'isomorphic-style-loader-forked/useStyles'
import React from 'react'
import s from './CardButton.css'

interface CardButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  onClick?: () => void
}

const CardButton = ({ children, onClick, ...rest }: CardButtonProps) => {
  useStyles(s)
  return (
    <Button ghost type="primary" className={s.root} onClick={onClick} {...rest}>
      {children}
    </Button>
  )
}
export default CardButton
```

However for your question maybe this answer helps more [How to wrap up Ant Design with Styled Components and TypeScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704785/how-to-wrap-up-ant-design-with-styled-components-and-typescript)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Your second exemple, I try it but I have always a grey button, I want to create a Button who override AntD Button and apply on it after a personalize style with TypeScript and styled Components. But Without personalize style I think the button must be like of a Ant Design Button .

Answer (score 2):

There is answer in FAQs in setyled components website.
Below I'm overriding default background color of Antd button.

```
import React from "react";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Button } from "antd";
import styled from "styled-components";

const MyButton = styled(Button)`
  &&& {
    background: red;
  }
`;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MyButton>Click</MyButton>
    </div>
  );
}
```